# Strategy Pattern using java 8 and service injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Strategy Pattern for some custom validation that doesn't involve only validation input with basic operations but I do need to call some other services to validate the data.

At the beginning I used the example mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/validations-using-enum) which uses enums to have different strategies but of course it was not possible to inject my services in the enum so now I'm looking at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern) that leverages to java 8 for more clarity.

My idea is to have an interface with has one method `validate()` and have generic input for different objects I could send it and then a class implementing that interface that would have different validations based on object type and dispatches requests to different services, but on the other hand I'm kinda loosing the enum advantage on having different strategies which I could select for instance based on specific user settings.

Any idea how to have both of these advantages?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that enums and the strategy pattern don't really mix.

The ideal use case for an enum is something that represents an exhaustive set of choices. [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) representing Monday to Sunday, for example. The problem with using this, in addition to not being able to autowire any other beans, is that your enum will continue to grow as the number of validations increase.

The strategy pattern allows you to use a potentially infinite number of possible strategies, provided it obeys the contract. Take [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), for example. There could be no exhaustive list of possible comparators, because it could never fulfill everyone's use-cases.

It makes more sense to define each of your possible strategies as a component

```
@Component 
class NonNullValidationStrategy implements ValidationStrategy {
    private final MyService service;

    //constructor

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyClass foo) {
        return foo != null;
    }
}
```

How you would obtain an instance of the right strategy when you need it will depend on details you haven't provided. Maybe autowiring with a qualifier is a possibility.

---

Spring already has it's [own way of defining validations, via interfaces and annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). I suggest you pursue that before rolling your own solution.

Comment: ```How you would obtain an instance of the right strategy when you need it will depend on details you haven't provided```
I kinda did, it's based on user settings, like you would have a Settings class which you could select which validations you want to happen.

Comment: @user2137817 When the user is selecting strategies, autowire the `List<ValidationStrategy>` of all strategies, then store the sub-list of strategies with the user.

Answer (score 0):

It'd like to suggest using javax.validation groups, see more about it [here](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/) especially `@Validated(OnCreate.class)`

If you want to apply strategy pattern at the controller level and deeper than see [this article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/implementing-the-strategy-pattern-with-spring-de2bad3abc2f) and especially [**my comment**](https://medium.com/@art.ptushkin/it-is-not-appropriate-to-add-a-method-to-the-interface-which-is-needed-only-to-collect-a-map-c6f88098d17c), because there is described not a pretty clean solution.

Comment: so your proper solution is to auto wire all the strategies one by one and affect them to enum values instead of letting spring auto wiring everything?

Comment: No, let spring autowire Map of<String, Service> where String is a bean name, you won't do it with enum on easy way. If you want a map with Enum key, then you have to collect it by hands (put) at a `@Bean` method